# Mac Mail - Stagger / batch download emails from gmail over imap

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

Ive got several gmail accounts and google apps for business (depreciated free version) accounts. One of the my google apps for business accounts is 25gb.

I want to add it to mail on my MBP (osx - 10.10.5).

Is there a mode where i can stagger the downloading of the emails as trying to download 25gb of emails over imap will trigger a temporary imap freeze on my account on gmails end (the freeze lasts about 24 hours). To get around this is there a setting where i can download either in batches or or donwload up to the last years data, then i can donwload then next years etc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Mail.app included with OS X, there is no built-in way within the application itself.

There are other approaches.

## Lower Your Internet Speed

However, you could artificially limit the speed of your Internet connection while the initial synchronisation takes place.

You can limit your Internet connection using Apple's [Network Link Conditioner](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=Hardware%20IO%20Tools). See the [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) about how to get and set up this useful developer tool:

[image: Network Link Conditioner]

Using this approach will allow you to run Mail continuously without risking your IMAP access being limited.

## Manually Enable and Disable the Account

You could add the mail account, then manually enable and disable the account as desired.

**Mail.app > Mail (menu) > Preferences > Accounts > Enable Account (checkbox)**

You can measure the network traffic using Activity Monitor.app's Network view; see **Sent Bytes** and **Rcvd Bytes**.

**Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.app**

This would allow you to watch the initial synchronisation traffic climb to a reasonable level before disabling the account.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Answer (score 0):

A semi automation solution i just thought of would be to create an automator script to open mail.app at 20:00 and close it at 222:00 every night, that way it would only download for 2 hours, thus not triggering the block on the gmail account (values would have to be tweaked but my gut is 2 hours worth of emails wouldnt cause the account to block - subject to your internet speed)

Only caveat i can see is that you'd have to leave the machine open (if its a laptop) for the automator script to run